# Как сделать нечувствительным к регистру MessageFormatter в ICU?

Tags: php, yii2, i18n

В своем проекте на PHP Yii2 я использую форматирование сообщений. Начинал с вот этого [гайда](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/tutorial-i18n.md#%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE).

В итоге докопался, что все это проходит через расширение `Intl`, которое в свою очередь использует ICU и его класс `MessageFormatter`.

Столкнулся с проблемой. Например, у меня есть строка:

```
{gender, select, male{Уважаемый} female{Уважаемая} other{Уважаемый}} {name}!
```

Я передаю в нее параметры:

```
[
   'gender' => 'female',
   'name' => 'Екатерина',
]
```

Изначальную строку может редактировать пользователь. Я хочу, чтобы она работала и если в строке написано `{NAME}`, и если `{name}`, то есть чтобы расширение игнорировало регистр букв, как это делает, например, функция `str_ireplace` в PHP. Понимаю, что в форматтере логика, конечно, сложнее, но тем не менее.